# jQuery detect if dropdown is expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping, keypress

I develop the `jQuery` modal windows and I have a problem. When user press the escape key, my system find topmost window and close them.
But there is a problem if, for example, dropdown is open, I want first close dropdown and if user press escape again then close modal (I don't want remove focus).
Input `autocomplete` is exactly same problem. Is the some way to find if pressed escape key has some "browser" function?

Thanks for your help, and sorry for my bad English,
Petr

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this with regular `select` element because there's no reliable way to detect if select's dropdown list is open or not. However if you build a custom select like using `divs` or such, you can detect if the div is visible or not then if it is, you can prevent modal from closing in `beforeClose` method.

Below method assumes that dropdown list is contained inside a `div#select_elems`

```
beforeClose : function(e,u){
    if (e.which == 27 && $("#select_elems").is(':visible')) 
        return false;
}
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2fzCs/1/)**